# Domain Logic leaking into Queries in MVC.NET application using DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am trying to implement a query to fetch some projection of data to **MVC view** from DB managed by domain model.

I've read that MVC controllers returning static views should request **DTOs** from **Query handlers** or so-called **read model repositories** rather than using **aggregate root repositories** returning full fledged domain objects. This way we maximize performance (optimizing queries for needed data) and reduce a risk of domain model misuse (we can't accidentally change model with DTOs).

The problem is that some **DTO properties** can't directly map to **DB Table field** and may be populated based on some **business rule** or be a result of some condition that is not implicitly stated in DB. That means that the query acts upon some **logic leaking from domain**. I heard that it's not right and that queries should directly filter, order, project and aggregate data from DB tables (using linq queries and EF in my case).

I envision 2 solutions so far:

1) **Read model repositories** internally query full **domain model objects**, use them to populate **DTO properties** (importantly those requiring some business logic from them to use). Here we don't gain performance benefits as we act upon instantiated domain models.

2) The other solution is **cache** all ever required data in DB through probably **domain repositories** (dealing with aggregate roots) so queries act upon data fields (with cached values) without addressing to **domain logic**. The consistency of the cached data then will be maintained by domain repositories and that results in some overhead as well.

**Examples:**

1) business rule can be as simple as string representation of certain objects or data (across the system) i.e. formatting;

2) Business rule can be calculated field returning bool as in the simple domain model below:

```
// first aggregate root
public class AssignedForm
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string FormName {get;set}
    public ICollection<FormRevision> FormRevisions {get;set}
    public bool HasTrackingInformation
    {
        get
        {
           return FormRevisions.Any(
                      fr=>   fr.RevisionType==ERevisionType.DiffCopy 
                             && fr.FormRevisionItems.Any)
        }
    }

    public void CreateNextRevision()
    {
         if(HasTrackingInformation)
         {
         .......
         }
         .......
    }
}

public enum ERevisionType { FullCopy=0,DiffCopy=1 }

public class FormRevision
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public ERevisionType RevisionType {get;set}
   public ICollection<FormRevisionItem> FormRevisionItems {get;set}
}
```

And then we have a read model repository, say *IFormTrackingInfoReader* returning collection of objects

```
public class FormTrackingInfo
{
   public int AssignedFormId {get;set}
   public int AssignedFormName {get;set}
   public bool HasTrackingInformation {get;set}
}
```

The question is how to implement *IFormTrackingInfoReader* and populate *HasTrackingInformation* property **sticking to DRY principle and without domain leaking into query**. I saw people just return domain objects and use mapping to populate view model. Probably this is way to go. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I heard that...", "I've read that..." It would be good to see your sources. Personal opinion: Patternitis is hampering your ability to just get on with it and write code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like solution 1, the domain model is not persistent ignorant.

Personally, I prefer solution2. But the "ever required data" may be a problem. If new query requirement emerges, perhaps you'll need some data migration(I heard events replaying will do the trick when using event sourcing). So I'm thinking is there a hybrid solution: Use value objects to implement the derivations. And we can create new value object instances with dto.

```
public class SomeDto {

    public String getSomeDerivation() {
         return new ValueObject(some data in this dto).someDerivation();
    }
}
```

In this case, I think domain logic is protected and seperated from persistence. But I haven't tried this in real projects.

**UPDATE1:**

The hybrid solution does not fit your particular FormTrackingInfo case, but your solution two does. One example is (sorry, I'm not a .net guy, in Java)

```
public class CustomerReadModel {
     private String phoneNumber;
     private String ....//other properties

     public String getPhoneNumber() {
         return phoneNumber;
     }

     public String getAreaCode() {
         return new PhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber).getAreaCode();//PhoneNumber is a value object.
     }
}
```

But like I said, I haven't tried it in real projects, I think it's at most an interim solution when the cached data is not ready.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to return ICollection<FormTrackingInfo> using hybrid approach with value objects?

Comment: @ddv answer updated, I'm afraid this solution does not work if the data needed is not in the readmodel.